# WPS and writing in arabic/persian language

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wps-spreadsheet

I have a problem in using WPS.

When I write in WPS writer everything works fine and the result is same as I want but when I work with WPS presentation and spreadsheet I can't change direction to RTL and every letter gets separated, and they are not the shape as they should be
(i am using Ubuntu 20.04 and WPS all languages 2016)

these are the photos:

WPS spreadsheet
[image]

and

Expected look

[image]

Thank you for your participation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So now I can say **LibreOffice** is better for languages which need to use RTL.
But consider using Google.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Setting > Pragraph`

[image: image of step 1]

then select direction: `right to left`

[image: image of step 2]